# Tracing the source of browser malware (if it's malware per se)

Tags: malware, web-browser, firefox

I'm on [a page](http://audacity.238276.n2.nabble.com/Audacity-help-Audacity-stops-recording-after-a-few-minutes-td279929.html) that is exhibiting some malware, in the form of this code being run when I click the link to `http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~raa110/audacity/AudacityHelp.html#DMA` -- which has been a 404 since my first try but the malware injection occurs before that page is even opened:

```
(function(){var f='www.super-resume.com/#__';f='https://href.li/?http://'+f;function hasLocalStorage(){try{localStorage.setItem('a','a');localStorage.removeItem('a');return true}catch(e){return false}};if(!document.addEventListener||!hasLocalStorage())return;var g=window.has_more_ads||window.has_st||(document.referrer&&document.referrer.match(/(:\/\/www\.(google|bing)\.|search\.(yahoo|ask)\.com\/)/i));var h=!document.location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(spssx-discussion|rhodes--22|vtk\.1045678|itk-users\.7|astronomia-e-astrofotos\.1069742|jsmastronomy.30143|jsmtst.2343515)\./);var j=!Nabble||!Nabble.isEmbedded;if(!g||!h||!j)return;if(!localStorage.dwp){$('td.footer-right').prepend('<span id="dis'+'ablep'+'op0"><a id="dis'+'ablep'+'op1" href="javascript:void(0)">Disa'+'ble Po'+'pup A'+'ds</a> | </span>');$('#dis'+'ablep'+'op1').click(function(){localStorage.dwp=1;typeof notice=='function'&&notice('Po'+'pup ads have been dis'+'abled',3000,1000);$('#dis'+'ablep'+'op0').remove()})}var k=localStorage.st;var l=new Date().getTime();var m=60*60*1000;var n=!k||l>parseInt(k)+m;if(!n)return;var o='width=1,height=1,left='+(screenX+outerWidth/2)+',top='+(screenY+outerHeight/2);function safari_trigger(){document.removeEventListener('click',safari_trigger,false);var a=window.open(f,'pu_',o);var b=document.createElement('a');b.setAttribute('href','data:text/html,<scr'+'ipt>window.close();</scr'+'ipt>');b.style.display='none';document.body.appendChild(b);var c=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');c.initMouseEvent('click',true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,true,false,false,true,0,null);b.dispatchEvent(c);document.body.removeChild(b)};function firefox_trigger(){document.removeEventListener('click',firefox_trigger,false);var a=window.open(f,'pu_',o);if(a){a.blur();try{var b=a.window.open('about:blank');b.close()}catch(i){};window.focus()}};function simple_trigger(){document.removeEventListener('click',simple_trigger,false);var a=window.open(f,'pu_',o);if(a){a.blur();window.focus()}};function chrome_trigger(b){var a=b.currentTarget;var c=a.href;a.href=f;window.open(c,'_blank')};function ready(a){if(document.readyState!='loading')a();else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',a)};ready(function(){var a=navigator.userAgent;var b=a.indexOf('Chrome')>=0?chrome_trigger:a.indexOf('Firefox')>=0?firefox_trigger:a.indexOf('MSIE')>=0||a.indexOf('Trident/')>=0?chrome_trigger:a.indexOf('iPhone')>=0?chrome_trigger:a.indexOf('Safari')>=0?safari_trigger:false;if(b){var c=document.querySelectorAll('a');for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){var d=c[i].getAttribute('href');if(d&&d.indexOf('javascript:')==-1){function _wrapper(e){localStorage.st=l;if(localStorage.dwp==1)return;b(e)};c[i].addEventListener('click',_wrapper,false)}}}})})();
```

It opens a tiny window and pretends to click various things, I guess to simulate real user browser clicks in order to scam ad revenue.  As soon as you click this pop-under's taskbar entry to investigate, it closes.

My question is, what's injecting this?  I doubt nabble.com has the malware, nor York U's 404 page; plus I cannot reproduce this behaviour in a private window.  The developer pane just says it's anonymous (I captured this by clicking the pause symbol, then the link you can see on the page):

[image: malware caught during click]

I don't have any strange plugins or addons, just what comes with stock Firefox, plus zotero and adblock plus, none of which have caused me problems before.

Firefox 51.0.1 (32-bit) on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

**update**

After a computer and browser restart, returning to the nabble page, pausing the debugger, and clicking the link now shows many sources, but still a SOURCE0, but it doesn't seem to have malware (or it's different malware): http://pastebin.com/zJi6P5Ay

**update 2**

Spybot Search & Destroy did not find anything related to super-resume.com or any malware--just tracking cookies and recent file lists.

**update 3**

Programs and Features does not show anything suspicious--only things installed on purpose and nothing extra.  The most recently installed program (a day or two ago) was Spotify--and I found this link (can't post, not enough rep, but second match on google for 'malware from spotify installer', FROM SPOTIFY COMMUNITY FORUMS) but they're supposed to have fixed that problem already.  Plus I can't see why they would be injecting in existing windows' click handlers--that link describes more a pattern of just opening new browser windows whenever Spotify likes to, not whenever the user clicks something on an unrelated web page.

Comment: report it to the page where you found it and leave it at that, it can be generated on the server side and unless you have access to their source code you wont be able to move forward

Comment: That page no longer exists so we cannot help unless you have a copy of the source. It could be anything and without the source of the page, we will never know.

Comment: @JulianKnight It's not the page that's 404ing that has the malware.  It's always been 404ing for me.  Before the link even goes anywhere the malware gets activated, on the nabble page.

Comment: @Purefan It's not reproducible in private, as I said.  Plus the source doesn't seem to contain links to anything like this, just standard JS libs.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make sense. That non-existent page redirects to a 404 page that doesn't contain malware. If you are seeing something different, it must be a local issue, most likely something infecting your browser.

Comment: @JulianKnight That's exactly what I'm saying and asking about.  What could be locally injecting this, if I don't have any rogue plugins or addons installed?

Comment: I think it would help to make the question rather more clear. Just because you cannot *see* the malware, doesn't mean it isn't there. You should run a malware check/clean application or two which will likely find the issue.

Comment: @JulianKnight I'll try but I had already included the relevant info.  Maybe you could be more specific as to how to make it more clear.  Meanwhile I am running malware checks, but my question was how to trace the origin of this SOURCE0 stuff, meanwhile.  (Also because Windows Defender had already not been finding anything even with realtime protection enabled.)

Comment: That code is being injected which is why you cannot make sense of it. You can prove that by accessing the URL via a different browser or using something like wget on it. There are many ways that can happen and unless you are a security researcher, it is a waste of your time and energy.

Comment: While Windows Defender is a reasonable tool, it is far from perfect and certainly doesn't find most PuP's and similar annoyances. Malwarebytes, et al are the tools to use.

Comment: @JulianKnight I'm not sure how to respond to that.  From the site faq I don't see how it's anybody's business what's a waste of my time.  I am responding to an incident and would like help with that, so I can learn how to avoid future incidents.  Thank you for the malwarebytes recommendation, I will try them next.  I had gone with SpyBot only because it seemed to be recommended by HijackThis.  Per my update in the question it also didn't find any malware.

Comment: The originating page has 8 JS libraries of which 5 are trackers +1 AJAX call. None contain your offending script as far as I can tell & I get nothing when going to that page and clicking on the link so the issue is definitely local to you. If the anti-malware tools don't find it, I suggest, as before, using a different browser, if that is clear, you will have to reset the browser - possibly by deleting it, removing any remaining settings and then reinstalling.

Comment: To answer your question on how to improve your answer, I would word it similar to this: "I found some malware in _this page_, tried with another browser and it doesnt happen there, so I suspect its a local problem but my scans have not shown any infection..." The problem is that this makes the question fall out of scope for Security StackExchange

Comment: Yes, unless the york.ac.uk gave you a 404 along with the ad, it's dead. But my suspicion is you've been infected with adware that circumvents your browsers popup blocker by replacing links so you'll click on them

Comment: I've seen this "malware" on two different devices, one mobile and one desktop, using a nabble site. Sounds like a malicious ad, not a local problem

Comment: I have just also experienced this when selecting a link from a Nabble page and had the same thing also about a week ago. Looking at the page later there is nothing wrong with the link